# adb.exe process crashes after running xamarin UI test in visual studio 2017 using windows 10 machine

Tags: c#, xamarin, adb

I have been getting the below error for a while now. I have tried all possible options that are available on various blogs to do with appinitializer. I have also tried to run the same xamarin UI test from USB connected local device and on visual studio Kit Kat emulator. However for some reason I get the below said error with each and every device/emulator and any appinitializer setting. I am using Visual Studio 2017 latest update and xamarin corss platform project with git source control. I had to move my android SDK on a different drive due to space constraint on C drive. I have changed the registry key for Android SDK and this doesn't solve the error. (Not sure if this could have been cause of failure)

Even if i dont run my test and just run the below command, i get same error and adb.exe process crashes:

> E:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages -f -e

The interesting bit is everything works fine on Mac.

I have raised this with Xamarin developers support however haven't heard fro them yet!!!!

Any help is highly appreciated!!

> SetUp : System.Exception : Failed to execute:
>
> E:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages -f -e - exit code: -1073740940
>
> package:/data/app/SmokeTestApp/SmokeTestApp.apk=com.android.smoketest
>
> package:/data/app/WidgetPreview/WidgetPreview.apk=com.android.widgetpreview
>
> at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Processes.ProcessRunner.Run(String path, String arguments, IEnumerable`1 noExceptionOnExitCodes)
>
> at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.Adb.AdbProcessRunner.Run(String adbArguments, Int32[] noExceptionsOnExitCodes)
>
> at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.Queries.QueryAdbInstalledPackages.Execute(AdbProcessRunner processRunner)
>
> at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.LocalAndroidAppLifeCycle.EnsureInstalled(String appPackageName, ApkFile testServerApkFile)
>
> at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor(IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration, IExecutor executor)
>
> at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp(AppDataMode appDataMode)
>
> at iBCU.UI.Test.AppInitializer.StartApp(Platform platform) in C:\Users\Source\Repos\Test\AppInitializer.cs:line 15
>
> at UI.Test.Tests.BeforeEachTest() in C:\Users\Source\Repos\Tests.cs:line 26
>
> Full log file: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\log-2017-07-13_13-58-38-861.txt
>
> Skipped IDE integration, connection failed.
>
> Android test running Xamarin.UITest version: 2.0.9
>
> Initializing Android app on device emulator-5554 with installed app: com.bcu.ibcu.activities
>
> Skipping local screenshots. Can be enabled with EnableScreenshots() when configuring app.
>
> Signing apk with Xamarin keystore.

Comment: `exit code: -1073740940`.... What version of `adb` do you have installed on your Windows PC? The latest is `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39` (Part of Android SDK Build Tools v26)

Comment: it is the latest version 1.0.39.

Comment: Solved the mystery of epic Xamarin UI test failure on windows machine  It was simple case of replacing "platform-tools" folder v 26 in android sdk with v25. The v25 is installed by default by VS2017 however if by mistake upgrade it using android sdk manager, there is no way you can roll back. So the hack is to replace the platform-tools folder with someone who has platform-tools version 25.Happy days 

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I replaced the SDK platform tools with the 23 version.
You can download it here:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23-windows.zip